# Wordpress Multisite - Can 2 domains share a database of users?

Tags: multisite

I'm creating a Wordpress site for a client. In the future, my client would like to have a second site that uses Wordpress as well. Ideally, we'd like people that have accounts on the first site to be able to use that same account on the second site. Is this something that can be achieved with Wordpress Multisite? If so, how?

The kickers is that each site would need to have it's own domain. For example, http://www.firstblog.com and http://www.secondblog.com would be two different sites sharing the same user accounts.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress multisite only has one table for users, so yes, users can use the same account on both sites. You will just have to be sure to set the appropriate role on each site, as network users are not necessarily users of a given site.

Comment: The FAQ's I've seen only reference multisite installs as being subdomains of the main domain. Admittedly I don't know a lot about how domains work in this regard. Is there a step by step process anywhere that will help me get a multisite wordpress installed on two different domains (not subdomains)?

Comment: There are plugins out there that do domain mapping, so that your network sites (whether subdomains or subfolders) can be assigned their own domains after initially installing multisite on one domain. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ . I believe there's also an ebook out there for purchase if you need more info.